# calculating time in C - AIX machine

Tags: c, aix

I am editing time value using a variable of type `struct tm` (adding some seconds to `tm->tm_sec`), but I am getting wrong results after doing `mktime(&t)`.

Doing so in Linux gets me proper results, but in AIX not. What could be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main ()
{
struct tm tm;
struct tm *end;
time_t t;
char str[20] = {'\0'};

//if (strptime("7 Feb 2013 01:47:30", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm) == NULL)
if (strptime("2012-10-17-01-07-30", "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", &tm) == NULL)
{printf("Error\n");
}
tm.tm_sec = (tm.tm_sec + 1200);
//tm.tm_sec = 12;
//t = mktime(&tm);
//t = t + 12;
//end =localtime(&t);
strftime(str,20,"%Y %m %d %H %M %S",&tm);
printf("str is %s\n",str);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. How does the code look like, how do you compile etc

Comment: How do you handle `tm_sec > 60`? I believe that the behavior is undefined if you don't. And what's the point of adding seconds to `struct tm` when doing it with `time_t` is so much easier?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct answer is to use `time_t`, which is a large number representing the time in seconds since midnight of 1 Jan 1970. Adding arbitrary number of seconds here becomes very trivial.

I expect that if you are just adding seconds to `tm->tm_sec`, it overflows, and that causes the result to be incorrect. If you are unlucky, you will need to ripple your change in seconds all the way through to year (adding 5 seconds to 31 Dec 2013 23:59:56 will take you to 01 Jan 2014 00:00:01). Which of course can be done, but instead of:

t =+ 5;

you get about a dozen steps along the line of

tm.tm_sec += 5;
   if (tm.tm_sec >= 60) 
   {
      tm.tm_sec -= 60;
      tm.tm_min += 1;
      if (tm.tm_min >= 60)
      {
         ... And so on ... 
      }
   }

It gets even more interesting if you overflow the days in a month, since you then have to take into account of the number of days in each month, 28, 29, 30 or 31 depending on which month [and if it's a leap-year or not].

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively what Mats said:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main ()
{
  struct tm tm;
  time_t t;
  char str[20] = {'\0'};

  if (strptime("2012-10-17-01-07-30", "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", &tm) == NULL) {
    printf("error\n");
  }
  t = mktime(&tm);
  t += 1200;
  tm = *localtime(&t);
  strftime(str,20,"%Y %m %d %H %M %S",&tm);
  printf("str is %s\n",str);

  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
cc -o t t.c && ./t
str is 2012 10 17 02 27 30
```